# Python: Overlapping regex search

Tags: python, regex

So if I create a program in python (3.7) that looks like this:

```
import re
regx = re.compile("test")
print(regx.findall("testest"))
```

and run it, then I will get:

```
["test"]
```

Even though there are two instances of "test" it's only showing me one which I think is because a letter from the first "test" is being used in the second "test". How can I make a program that will give me `["test", "test"]` as a result instead?

Comment: Yeah, that question helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use a capturing group with a lookahead `(?=(regex_here))`:

```
import re
regx = re.compile("(?=(test))")
print(regx.findall("testest"))

>>> ['test', 'test']
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex expressions are greedy. They consume as much of the target string as possible. Once consumed, a character is not examined again, so overlapping patterns are not found.

To do this you need to use a feature of python regular expressions called a look ahead assertion. You will look for instances of the character `t` where it is followed by `est`. The look ahead does not consume parts of the string.

```
    import re

    regx = re.compile('t(?=est)')

    print([m.start() for m in regx.finditer('testest')])
```

`[0,3]`

More details on this page: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html